# Get nearest form item jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a form with some items and I have to send ajax request when those items changes. After server answer I need put some HTML in nearest li tag on which user clicked

```
$('.form').on('change', function(e){
    fastSearch($('.form'));
});

function fastSearch(formItem){

    var form = formItem.serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        data : form,
        url : '/ajax/fast.filter.php'
    }).done(function(data){
        var html = '<span class="filter-budge show">' + data + '</span>';
    }).fail(function(){

    });
}
```

Comment: Add your html structure to the question so we can better understand where you want to put it.

Comment: you can use perv and next or closest function

Comment: Please share your HTML code here as the visualization of a developer can differ a lot from what you just said. Then anything we suggest will be a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do two things.

1. First on change event store current element reference.

   `ex. var ref=$(this);`// or respective element.
   Pass this reference to t=your `fastSearch` function.
2. When server response came then perform closest search like.

   `$(ref).closest("li").html(response);`